# How to check if a deqeue has no elements (Empty)

Tags: python, numpy, deque

Below is a part-code of my program where the program only should go inside the function if a the deqeue for both red_dir and blue_dir are not empty

```
from collections import  deque
import numpy as np

red_direction=deque(maxlen=1)
blue_direction=deque(maxlen=1)

def is_collision(red_dir,blue_dir,pr,pb,S2,S5,SWitch_pos_2,SWitch_pos_5):

 #checks if both direction are not empty
 if red_dir and blue_dir: 
  if red_dir[0]!=blue_dir[0]and np.abs(WP_r[0][0][0]-WP_b[0][0][0])>3:
     cv2.putText(img_dst, "ptential collision", (1204,417), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.55, (0,255,255), 1)
  if red_dir[0]!=blue_dir[0] :
     if np.abs(pr[0][0][0]-SWitch_pos_2[0][0])<0.2 and np.abs(pb[0][0][0]-SWitch_pos_5[0][0])<0.2:
         if S2!=S5:
           cv2.putText(img_dst, "collision", (1204,417), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.55, (0,0,255), 1) 
           cv2.waitKey(1000)
#calling the function
is_collision(red_direction,blue_direction,WP_r,WP_b,SW2,SW5,s2_p,s5_p)
```

at the first 30 frames the red_direction and blue direction are empty, so as a sanity check i printed one of and got:
print(red_direction)
deque([], maxlen=1)
deque([], maxlen=1)
deque([''], maxlen=1)
deque([''], maxlen=1)

The problem is that when i call the function, it immediately goes in the `if red_dir and blue_dir:`, although its empty at the beginning !

**So does `deque([], maxlen=1)` means that its not empty?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think it immediately meets the first condition? It doesn't when I do it

Comment: @NicolasGervais. Because i made a sanity check and such that it prints true if it goes inside. and at the same time i checked the dequeue and it was empty

Comment: The answer is no. You see the empty deque and its maxlen. An empty deque is *falsy* as usual. Use `if deque:`, or `len(deque)` or `bool(deque)` to find.